# Can data and decoder reconstructed output have different channel dimensions for reconstruction loss in a VAE?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am implementing a Variational Auto-Encoder using most of the foundation from the [Keras code snippet tutorial](https://keras.io/examples/generative/vae/).

My input data currently is 500 samples by 125 channels (EEG data) but I am purposefully making my decoded output to only have 1 channel e.g., `[500,1]`. My reconstruction loss is a binary cross-entropy comparing my input data and reconstructed decoder output `[500,125]` vs. `[500,1]`.

The code runs without any warnings or errors, but I am not sure whether it is OK to compare data with different channel dimensions and if that is being reflected in either my reconstruction loss or KL loss. Is Keras/TF taking into account the different channels and somehow able to make that comparison across all channels? OR is it only comparing the data from one channel? Any help as to what Keras is doing under the hood would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why this is works is due to broadcasting which is inspired by the [NumPy broadcasting semantics](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html#module-numpy.doc.broadcasting). As long as all dimensions match except for the ones that are missing or are `1`, then the tensor with the missing/`1`-dimension will be expanded to match the other tensor for the operation you do on them.

Basically: when, say, multiplying two tensors with dimensions `(500, 125)` and `(500, 1)`, the second tensor will be expanded to have the shape `(500, 125)` by "copying" the data (only it is not a copy but a view on the same data).

That's the reason why it works without raising errors. Whether it is factually correct is on you to figure out, though :)

The way it is implemented now is that you assume that the decoding must match every input channel equally, which might not be what you want and might give you just an 'average' decoding, basically a very 'blurred' decoding.

Comment: This is a great simple explanation and really clears up how I should be thinking about my training process. Thank you.